# How to Empty All Class Attributes from All HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to empty all html source code class attributes. For example, I have multiple elements values like div element, heading, and paragraph. Every HTML element content different class attributes just like below code.:

```
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title main-text-color ">My Mobile Phone is best
              </h5>
    <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    </p>
    <p class="py-2">
        <a class=" main-color btn  text-light " href="#" class=" ">MORE DETAIL
                </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Now I want to make it to be like the below code instead:

```
<div class="">
    <h5 class=" ">My Mobile Phone is best
              </h5>
    <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla nec imperdiet ligula. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas
    </p>
    <p class="">
        <a class="  " href="#" class=" ">MORE DETAIL
                </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

How do I do this with Javascript in a browser?

Comment: I have tried a lot but there is no any way to solve it. please help me to empty all of the html elements.

Comment: You will have to use recursion here...

Comment: @EugeneSunic Recursion isn't needed

Comment: Please provide me solution how to do it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance hmm, you say that you can get all of the dom elements and their children in a one dimensional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the query string `[class]` and use `querySelectorAll` to select all elements with a `class` attribute, and then set their `className` to the empty string:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[class]').forEach((elm) => {
  elm.className = '';
});
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title main-text-color ">My Mobile Phone is best
  </h5>
  <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </p>
  <p class="py-2">
    <a class=" main-color btn  text-light " href="#" class=" ">MORE DETAIL
                </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

If you wanted to completely remove the class attributes, rather than setting them all to the empty string, instead use

```
elm.removeAttribute('class');
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[class]').forEach((elm) => {
  elm.removeAttribute('class');
});
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title main-text-color ">My Mobile Phone is best
  </h5>
  <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </p>
  <p class="py-2">
    <a class=" main-color btn  text-light " href="#" class=" ">MORE DETAIL
                </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

On older browsers that don't support `NodeList.prototype.forEach`, you can use `for..of` (if ES6 supported) or a plain `for` loop with manual iteration over indicies.

Comment: You older browser, you can use Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[class]')) maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this:

get All html elements, loop through them and set class attribute to empty string

```
const htmlElements = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (let i = 0; i < htmlElements.length; i++) {
  htmlElements[i].className=''
}
```